# understanding of cumsum dfunction

Tags: matlab, svd, cumsum

let us suppose that we have  SVD decomposition of some matrices

```
[U E V]=svd(X);
```

and i want to  sketch graph of  cumulative sum of singular value ,so i have done  like this

```
sigmas=diag(E);
 %figure; plot(log10(sigmas)); title('Singular Values (Log10 Scale)');
figure; plot(cumsum(sigmas) / sum(sigmas)); title('Cumulative Percent of Total Sigmas');
```

and get following  graph

[image]

i wound to understand this chart,as we see till  approximately 4,line is not linear,but after the 4 it became linear,does it means that first four  singular value have most impact on the  chart?and others  effect  is just  a bit small?thanks in advance

Comment: How many SVD's do you get? I initially assumed that there were four values, and if you plotted with `plot(..., '*b')` you would see that this is not a piecewise linear plot, but just four data points connected together. However, I am no longer convinced that is the case. Can you provide more information about the variables `X` and `sigmas` ?

Comment: sigmas are 15  ,they are 15 singular value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the data, I cannot explain *why* the singular values appear the way they do here. However, generally in mathematics, larger singular values imply more "importance" to that data.

I'm not sure why we are looking at the normalized cumulative sum; however, from these results we can infer that there are distinct "groups" of singular values with identical (or nearly identical) values, and that the earlier groups have larger singular values.

Again, without seeing the data, this seems to imply that there are artificial "groupings" within the eigenvectors of the matrix. And, because smaller smaller values give less weight to those eigenvectors, your first singular values represent the more "important" eigenvalues.

It is up to you for your data and application to decide if the effect of later singular values is "small" or not.